# How to sort a queryset of models in django by its function

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I thought I knew how this worked but there is a bug which I can't seem to figure out.

I have a query set where each of the models has a 'hotness()' method which returns dynamically a hotness value.

Here is my code:

```
 from item.models import Item

 items = Item.objects.all()
 items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.hotness, reverse=True)


 # it does not work.

 for i in items:

     print i.hotness() # totally out of order, not even close
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: `x.hotness` is a column (or a property) - which will almost always return true, and `x.hotness()` is a method call. Make sure you are sorting by the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your exact usecase you're not converting your QuerySet to a list before using it on `sorted()`.

```
items = list(Item.objects.all())
items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.hotness(), reverse=True)
```

should work.

Comment: I am quite sure you mean `x.hotness()` in the lambda.

Comment: Ouch, I thought I read in the docs somewhere that the key parameter in sorted needs to be passed a function, (not its returned value). Amateur mistake by me, thank you.

Comment: I just read your blog post "what have your tried", before asking on stack overflow I spent 1/4 a day trying out random methods but never actually re-read the docs :p Nice blog though

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang I didn't write it, someone much, much smarter and better than me wrote it but it always hits home somewhere :)